# Eclipse / RAP / Tabris: Is it possible to invoke code locally on the client?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

I'd like to be able to use service discovery APIs (e.g. jmdns) on the client to find services running on the ***client's local network*** (in a desktop app).

Not knowing a huge amount about RAP architecture, with the code actually running on the server does this mean it's not possible to do this? Would the API calls only discover services running server-side?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats right. Using service discovery APIs (e.g. jmdns) would only discover services running on the server side.
The Tabris client for iOS is written in pure Objective-C and only renders the UI of the Java Application that runs on the server and provides access to native functionality on the iOS device.

Comment: Ah OK that's a shame really. I guess if you add the ability to push code over to the client and (somehow) run it from Objective-C then Apple wouldn't approve the client app...